# Returning pointer to the beginning of an array

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I've strarted learning programming about a week or two ago and I made a simple function with dynamic memory allocation. It works fine (I guess... nothing crashed yet) but i wonder if there's any other way to return to the beginning of an array instead of saving it's adress to another variable.

```
void time()
{
    int* tab, b;
    int q, i;
    clock_t start, stop; //time.h cstdlib
    double time;


    cout << "Number of elements in array: ";
    cin >> q;
    tab = new int[q];
    b = (int) tab;
    start = clock();
    for (i = 0; i < q; i++)
    {
        tab[i] = i;
        tab[i] += 50;
    }
    stop = clock();
    czas = (double)(stop - start)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    cout << "Time: "<< time << endl;
    tab = (int*) b; 
    delete [] tab;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

No, there is no way to take a pointer and return to its "base address". There are slightly different patterns that you could use and tricks, but they're rarely worth it.

By the way, in C++, the `*` is "part of the name" instead of "part of the type" in a declaration. This means that `int* tab, b` is like `int (*tab), b`, and only `tab` is a pointer. This is why you need to cast `tab` to an `int` right now when you assign it to `b`. You should either do `int* tab, * b` or declare them individually on different lines.

Comment: Yep, different lines ftw. Some people still use this one edge case as their sole justification for proposing right-alignment of asterisks (yeah I know that fits the grammar but that's about it!) which boggles the mind frankly. There are _so_ many good reasons to keep thinking of the `*` as "part of the type" in actual use. Hey ho.

Answer (score 2):

This:

```
b = (int) tab;
```

Is illegal.  You are storing (and later resurrecting) a pointer in an `int`.  That won't work at all on some machines (e.g. ones where `int` and `int*` have different sizes).  You should never use C-style `(foo)bar` casts in C++.  You can simply store your pointer in another `int*` pointer.  But in your example program you don't need to store it at all, because you never change the address inside the original pointer.

If I were to rewrite your code, I'd do this:

```
void time()
{
    int q;
    cout << "Number of elements in array: ";
    cin >> q;

    vector<int> tab(q);
    clock_t start = clock();
    for (int i = 0; i < q; i++)
    {
        tab[i] = i;
        tab[i] += 50;
    }
    clock_t stop = clock();
    double time = double(stop - start)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    cout << "Time: "<< time << endl;
}
```

The above does pretty much the same thing, but is simpler and safer.